# How to simulate an Availability Zone (AZ) failure in Azure?

Tags: azure, aks

I'm setting up a cross AZ AKS cluster. I would like to simulate a failure of an AZ to test the behaviour of cluster and application after such an event.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to simulate an availability zone failure in Azure, there is no functionality available to customers to do this.

You could look to manually take some nodes offline in the VM scale set to simulate the node failure, but that would not cover any failures in the master nodes.